# Какой аналог utl_i18n.unescape_reference() есть в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

Чем можно заменить оракловую функцию utl_i18n.unescape_reference (или весь пакет) в PostgreSQL? То есть ближайший по смыслу аналог, который поможет заменить экранированные html символы. Например, чтобы мигрировать следующий запрос из Oracle в PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT utl_i18n.unescape_reference('Tom &amp; Jery: Tom&apos;s revenge') FROM DUAL;
```

> Tom & Jery: Tom's revenge

Comment: Самый первый контакт с постгресом. Пока в гугле не встретил простой прямой ответ на этот вопрос, но пока даже не все концепции уловил, поэтому гуглить несколько сложнее.